# How can i initialize component state with Props and make some changes to this state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

- I have a screen which has a state property `tags` which is initialized with props - the props are an array of objects.
- When set i use `this.state.tags` to render the object items in a FlatList which i then interact with by moving them around and swapping them using [panResponder](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder).

  - My problem is on the initial render the items displayed but i cannot move them but when i make a change in the code to force a re-render - then i can move the items -  what could i be doing wrong.

```
class MyTags extends PureComponent<Props, State> {   

  props: Props;

  state: State = {
    tags: this.props.tags,
  };

  panResponder: PanResponder;

  componentWillMount = async () => {
    this.panResponder = this.createPanResponder();

    await this.setState({tags: this.props.squadTemplate})
  }


  render() {
      const {tags} = this.state

      let myCards = [];
      for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      myCards.push({
        id: i,
        card: (
          <CardHolder
            tag={this.state.tags[i-1]}
          />
        ),
      });
    }

      const slice1 = myCards.filter(card => card.card.props?.tag.new === true );



    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={slice1}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <TouchableHighlight
              style={{ marginHorizontal: 10, alignSelf: "center" }}
              >
              {item.card}
            </TouchableHighlight>
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        />
</View>
)
```

Comment: `componentWillMount` is to be deprecated, you should use `componentDidMount` instead. Then, if you use no promise in your lifecycle method, you've got no reason to make it asynchronous and await the setState call

Comment: Thanks - I will adjust the lifecycle methods - about the async calls when done without awaiting(waiting) for all the necessary data to be obtained there wont be anything to set to State.